# What is the benefit of cloudfares or inkapsulas etc ddos protection

Tags: linux, nameserver, ddos

My Server get even more attacked via DDOS. And im thinking about buying a service like cloudfare or incapsule for preventing DDOS.

But i dont understand one thing. When the attackers see that the domain is protected than they can attack the server via IP? Or did i understand their service wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we're not the vendors of these services.  You should ask the vendors to explain to you how their services would protect you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about "it protect you from DDOS"? And CloudFlare is free ;)

> When the attackers see that the domain is protected than they can attack the server via IP?

And where do they get the IP from? CLoudFlare etc. act as proxies - they handle all traffic through their clusters. So the traffic only goes to you when their proxy forwards it. Obviously you have to move your IP... because whoever right now DDOSses you already knows your IP ;)

Comment: I understand that they act as proxy for static files like images etc...

Comment: No, they act as PROXY. For everything. They put their IP into the internet and forard all traffic that is not cached to you. How you think they proxy static files ONLY? That would be magic.

Comment: thank you for your help. i have to learn more about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

"When the attackers see that the domain is protected than they can attack the server via IP? Or did i understand their service wrong? "

Yes, the attacker could still attack your IP if they know it. If you want to reduce the probability of your server IP being found/attacked, then please look at these [general security guidelines](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170166-General-website-security-guidelines).